# My console didn't run correctly in Windows Server 2008 Task Scheduler

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I wrote a console to check a list of websites are available or not. I run it ok and after check all website, It will send to me an result email. But when I put it on Windows Server 2008 Task Scheduler and run each after 10 minutes, nothing happended. It runs but no email was sent to me? Any comment?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the user under which the task is running does not have network access. Try changing it to NETWORK_SERVICE